Sampling angles on a sphere: From a general covariance matrix to concentration parameter
I am trying to extract points on a sphere in python.
I have to localise event in the sky and produce a map using healpy.
During the test session I used the von Mises-Fisher since I assumed that variance for $\theta$ is the same as the one for $\phi$. All worked well and I was able to obtain a concentration parameter $\kappa$ by using $\kappa=1/\sigma^2$.
My function to evaluate the probability in a pixel was
def Mises_Fisher(theta,phi,DS_theta,DS_phi,conc):
    meanvec=hp.ang2vec(DS_theta,DS_phi)
    meanvec=np.asarray(meanvec,dtype=np.float128)
    norm=np.sqrt(np.dot(meanvec,meanvec))
    meanvec=meanvec/norm
    
    var=hp.ang2vec(theta,phi)
    var=np.asarray(var,dtype=np.float128)
    norm=np.sqrt(np.dot(var,var))
    var=var/norm
    
    factor=np.dot(conc*var,meanvec)
    factor=np.float128(factor)
    #Normalization is futile, we will devide by the sum
    #fullnorm=conc/(2*np.pi*(np.exp(conc)-np.exp(-conc)))
    ret=np.float128(np.exp(factor))#/fullnorm
    #ret=factor
    return ret

and then for each pixel in the healpy map, I can assign a probability.
Now I have a covariance matrix that is no more isotropic, how can I generate points on a sphere in this case? I know the existence of the Kent distribution, but I don't have the required quantities, like $\gamma$,$\beta$ and $\kappa$. I don't know if there is a way to obtain those given a covariance matrix.
To further complicate the problem, the matrix is in 11 dimension but I need only the projection to the (distance,$\theta$,$\phi$)-space to then produce the map.
For now I tried to extract from a multivariate Gaussian but since the Gaussian is on the tangent plane, for some variances the distribution produce angles that are outside the domain for $\theta$ and $\phi$.
Here is the code I'm using to extract the points
num_samples = 10**7
samples = np.random.multivariate_normal(perm_mean, perm_cov, num_samples)

phi = samples[:, 2]
theta = samples[:, 1]
print(np.min(theta),np.max(theta))
print(np.min(phi),np.max(phi))
print('starting mean values')
print('theta={}, phi={}'.format(perm_mean[1],perm_mean[2]))

The point is that for some matrices, the variance is such that angles can go outside the domain. I can't act on the matrices, those are given to me by some other codes and should be treated as fixed data.
Thank you all in advance!
*edit
Here I clarify and make my statement more rigorous.
So the matrix is a covariance matrix given me by another piece of code that I can't change. I have to evaluate the sky localisation of a Gravitational Wave (GW) event. In my case this implies to give 11 parameters, that include the sky position,to a program and this code gives me back a covariance matrix. For the scope of this question the program can be considered a black box, since I can't modify anything there.
Now I can sample from this matrix and obtain $\theta$ and $\phi$ i.e. the sky position.
Let us be the centre of a unit sphere, each point on the surface is identified by a vector pointing at the GW event sky coordinate. We can forget about the other parameters for now.
If the event is well localised, that means if the variance of the angles is "small" we can image to build a plane, tangent to the sky, with normal vector along the radial direction, starting from the GW position. Now if we sample a Gaussian distribution that has as parameters $\mu$ and $\Sigma$, with  $\mu$ the mean vector given by the 11  starting parameters and $\Sigma$ the cov matrix, we can obtain samples for $\theta$ and $\phi$. This works well but stats to fail once the variance is large enough and we start to "feel " that we are on a sphere and not on a plane. The distribution that solve this Issue is the Kent distribution. My question is
Given a mean vector $\mu$ and a covariance matrix $\Sigma$ it is possible to construct the necessary quantities needed in the Kent distribution?

Your remarks beginning "the matrix is in 11 dimension but I need only the projection to the (distance,θ,ϕ)-space" are opaque: what is "the matrix," what does it represent, and what is "the projection"?  Indeed, what is your question: is it to adopt some kind of probability model for data, or sample from a given model, or estimate parameters of a model, or maybe something else?

Hi and thanks for the comment, I edited the question to be more rigorous and to express better my needs. Hope is more clear now. The addenda is after the " *edit"

The covariance matrix evidently is a covariance of some data or some estimated random variables.  What exactly does it represent?  Although it could be a covariance matrix of angles $(\theta,\phi),$ there are other possibilities, such as the covariance matrix of coordinates in some map-like projection of the sky.

The covariance matrix is obtained from the Fisher Information Matrix (FIM). So it represents the covariance near the maximum-likelihood estimation of the parameters. Is not projected or anything else. The parameters are the distance of the GW so $dl$, $theta$, $\phi$ and a bunch of other parameters that concern the source (like the mass for example)

The difficulty with that is this is a covariance matrix of parameter estimates.  You cannot employ it to sample the angles: it solely gives information about the uncertainties in the estimates.

Hi whuber, you are right the covariance estimates the parameters. One can build on top of this using some approximation. If you have a FIM and a vector $\mu$ with the maximum likelihood values of the parameters then for some $\epsilon$ you can say that the true distribution is well approximated by a multivariate Gaussian with mean $\mu$ and covariance $\Sigma$ the latter given by the FIM. Maybe is a small region, but this can be done.
